# easier way to add rows to a tibble? (dummy cases, TRUE/FALSE sample)

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

I want to add some dummy cases to a tibble. Here's a very simplified version of my tibble (the original table has > 100 cols and it's not empty):

```
Test <- tibble(A1 = logical(),
               A2 = logical(),
               A3 = logical(),
               A4 = logical(),
               A5 = logical(),
               other_stuff = character())
```

This is a function to create a dummy case (N is the number or "answers", prob_T is the probability of TRUE):

```
make_dummy_case <- function(N, prob_T) {
    sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), N, prob = c(prob_T, (1 - prob_T)), replace=TRUE)}
```

So, `make_dummy_case(5, 0.5)` will produce five "answers" (or a logical vector of length N) with a 50/50 probability for TRUE.

Now I'd like to add a lot of dummy cases with varying probabilities to the tibble (add the N * 5 dummy answers to A1:A5).

My approach was to build a tibble with identical names and using `map2`, `as_tibble` and `rbind`. I somehow succeeded, but the solution looks quite complicated to me. **Is there a simpler way?**

```
dummy_cases <- as_tibble(map2(5, seq(0, 1, by = 0.02), make_dummy_case), .name_repair = "unique")
dummy_cases <- as_tibble(t(dummy_cases), .name_repair = "unique")
dummy_cases <- mutate(dummy_cases, other_stuff = NA_character_)
names(dummy_cases) <- names(Test)
rbind(Test, dummy_cases)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a 1 X 5 dataframe/tibble from the function `make_dummy_case`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

make_dummy_case <- function(N, prob_T) {
  sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), N, prob = c(prob_T, (1 - prob_T)), replace=TRUE) %>%
    t %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    setNames(paste0('A', 1:5)) %>%
    tibble()
}
```

Then you can do :

```
bind_rows(Test, map2_df(5, seq(0, 1, by = 0.02), make_dummy_case))

# A tibble: 51 x 6
#   A1    A2    A3    A4    A5    other_stuff
#   <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr>      
# 1 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE NA         
# 2 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE NA         
# 3 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE NA         
# 4 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE NA         
# 5 TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE NA         
# 6 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  NA         
# 7 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE NA         
# 8 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE NA         
# 9 TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE NA         
#10 FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  FALSE NA         
# … with 41 more rows
```